# Can't get result data with $http angularjs

Tags: http, angularjs

I'm trying to use $http, but why it return null result?

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('sender', function($http) {
    var newData = null;
    $http.get('test.html')
        .success(function(data) {
            newData = data;
            console.log(newData)
        })
        .error(function() {
            newData = 'error';
        });
    console.log(newData)
    return newData
})
```

Console say: http://screencast.com/t/vBGkl2sThBd4. Why my newData first is null and then is defined? How to do it correctly?

Comment: Hey, if my answer was what you were after please accept it so it doesn't stay open forever. Cheers!

Answer (score 20):

As YardenST said, `$http` is asynchronous so you need to make sure that all functions or display logic that are dependent on the data that is returned by your `$http.get()`, gets handle accordingly. One way to accomplish this is to make use of the "promise" that `$http` returns:

[**Plunkr Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/9w2jTg?p=preview)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('AvengersService', function ($http) {

    var AvengersService = {
        getCast: function () {
            // $http returns a 'promise'
            return $http.get("avengers.json").then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    };

    return AvengersService;
});


myApp.controller('AvengersCtrl', function($scope, $http, $log, AvengersService) {
    // Assign service to scope if you'd like to be able call it from your view also
    $scope.avengers = AvengersService;

    // Call the async method and then do stuff with what is returned inside the function
    AvengersService.getCast().then(function (asyncCastData) {
            $scope.avengers.cast = asyncCastData;
    });

    // We can also use $watch to keep an eye out for when $scope.avengers.cast gets populated
    $scope.$watch('avengers.cast', function (cast) {
        // When $scope.avengers.cast has data, then run these functions
        if (angular.isDefined(cast)) {          
            $log.info("$scope.avengers.cast has data");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Great answer!! I'm going to add this to my blog!! :)

Comment: @sk8terboi87ツ Then click that up vote; it's what it's for! :)

Comment: This definitely works, but I can't believe this is the most efficient way of creating a data factory in Angular. Either way, the OP should mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 5):

This JavaScript code is asynchronous.

```
console.log(newData)
return newData
```

Is executed before what inside `success`

```
newData = data;
console.log(newData)
```

So at first time, the newData is null (you set it to be null)

And when the http response is returned (inside the success), the newData gets its new value.

This is very common in Javascript, you should do all your work inside the `success`.