# Angular Resource malfunction

Tags: angularjs

I am using a resource call as follows:

[image: Resource code]

The baseUrl returns json as follows:

[image]

However when I call it from my controller like:

[image]

I get some really weird result as blow:
[image]

So my question is : what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get result data with $http angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671580/cant-get-result-data-with-http-angularjs)

Comment: Take a look at the $resouce source to see what you could do to make this work more like that: http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular-resource.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$http.get service returns promise. You should use this code:

```
var data;

Employee.query().then(function(_data) {
  data = _data;
  console.log(data);
});
```